# Cakephp3 retrieving matching or not exists from hasMany association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here's the situation - I have users that can take multiple tests - relatioship is `users` hasMany `tests`. Now, I need to write a select what would retrieve me all users that have `status = 1` ant that have either not taken any tests or their tests were taken more then six months ago. I have written the first part like this:

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all')
    ->where(['Users.status' => 1])
    ->matching('Tests', function($q) {
        return $q
            ->where(['Tests.created <' => new \DateTime('-6 months')]);
       });
```

Any ideas how I can add the second bit?

Comment: maybe using notMatching with created >= 6 months ago? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is not very clear but seems you simply don't want students that have at least one exam in the last 6 months

In this case I think that `notMatching` should do the job

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all')
    ->where(['Users.status' => 1])
    ->notMatching('Tests', function($q) {
        return $q
            ->where(['Tests.created >=' => new \DateTime('-6 months')]);
    });
```

Your situation is very similar to the one described [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching) in the cookbook

Comment: Thanks, that worked - we always overcomplicate our queries :(